# How can I export data from Zendesk?

Tags: python, csv, zendesk, zendesk-api

My org is using utilizing Zendesk for work orders. To do this, we have created custom fields to manage statuses and various other information.  I want to be able to export this data for reporting purposes to see what is completed, what is in progress, etc. but the 10 column limitation in Zendesk is an issue.  Can I use the API to export these work order tickets with a column for each custom field and get it into CSV?

Comment: That's not a programming question and as such off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific on which Zendesk product are you using? They have lots of different products (Zendesk Support, Zendesk Talk, Zendesk Chat, etc.).
Feel free to contact me through email.

Comment: I am using Zendesk support I believe.  I am working inside of the ticketing system, but we have temporarily repurposed it to house work orders.

Comment: P.S. If it's for work and you have a budget, there are two options. The simplest option is Acho.io, you can pull the data out as CSV and do some data analysis without writing any code. If you know how to code, have a data warehouse, and have days to spend you can try panoply.io. If you don't have a budget and you are good at coding, give Airbyte a try.

Answer (score 0):

Zendesk `Views` do have current 10 column limitation. Although Zendesk provides multiple api endpoints to export data from its products.

You can do following:

1. Export with the time-based `incremental export` api export. [Documentation link](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/ticket-management/incremental_exports/)
2. Export with Query based `search` endpoint. [Documentation link.](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/ticket-management/search/#export-search-results) There is also a zendesk community post "Support Search Reference"  on how to create search query. Do take a look at that!

IMO you probably want to go via route 2.

There's also an [Advanced Search marketplace app](https://www.zendesk.com/apps/support/advanced-search/) which is pretty handy and easy to use!

Vote this up , If you found this helpful!

Comment: I voted up, but I don't have enough reputation yet.  This is helpful, thank you.